# Construct a bijection $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy-1),\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

The question is :

> Construct a bijection $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy-1),\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Here $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy-1),\mathbb C)$ is the set of all homomorphisms $$\phi :\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy-1) \to \mathbb C\;\; \text{s.t.}\;\; \phi|_{\mathbb C}=\mathrm{id}|_{\mathbb C}.$$

Please someone give some hints how can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A homomorphism from $R=\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy-1)$ to $\Bbb C$ is a homomorphism
$\Phi$ from $\Bbb C[x,y]$ to $\Bbb C$ with $\Phi(xy-1)=0$. Each homomorphism $\Phi:\Bbb C[x,y]\to \Bbb C$ has has the form
$\Phi_{a,b}:f(x,y)\to f(a,b)$ where $a$, $b\in\Bbb C$. Then
$\Phi_{a,b}(xy-1)=ab-1$. So $\Phi_{a,b}$ defines a homomorphism
on $R$ iff $ab=1$, etc.

Comment: yeah I get your point but we have to construct  a bijection

Comment: I think one bijection will be like $\Phi_{a,b} \mapsto a $

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $~$ A $\mathbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1}]\to\mathbb{C}$ is determined by where $x$ is sent.

Comment: I didn't studied $\mathbb C$-algebra yet so if there is any other process please provide

Comment: @nisha "$\Bbb C$-algebra homomorphism" = "$\Bbb C$-linear ring homomorphism," which turns out to be **exactly** what you are studying in this problem.