# Construct a bijection explicitly.

Tags: ring-homomorphism

Construct a bijection $Hom_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy-1),\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C - \{0\}$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397337/construct-a-bijection-hom-mathbb-c-mathbb-cx-y-xy-1-mathbb-c-to-mat) the similar question lies but I can not find the exact bijection which is explicitly defined.

I considered the mapping $\phi_{a,b} \mapsto {a \over b},$ where $a,b \in \mathbb C$ with $ab=1$  but I can not show it one-one. It is of course  well-defined and surjective.

Can someone please say another mapping beyond it.

Thank you..